# Calculate sampling lattice matrix in 2D

Tags: sampling, matrix, 2d

The pattern in which the sample points are distributed in 2 dims, is called a
sampling lattice, and can be defined by a generator matrix.. In 2 dimensions, the generator matrix consists of 2 vectors. My Question is how we choose those vectors to produce the sampling matrix? Can two different generator matrix produce the same pattern?

For example, given this 
[image]

[image]

i think both of the pair vectors can produce the same sampling matrix